# Dojo chart not re-rendering to update series

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, highcharts, render

I have the following code, and what I would like to do is update the chart with values coming from an AJAX call on a button push (also on page start). The issue I am having is that the chart will not update or re-render. I have hard coded the values coming in from the server just as a test because I know I can get the values.

```
 require(["dojox/charting/Chart", 
                 "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", 
                 "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", 
                 "dojo/ready", 
                 "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
                 "dojo/request",
                 "dojo/dom",
                 "dojo/on"],
            function(Chart, Default, Lines, ready, theme, request, dom, on){ 
            ready(function(){
                var policeResChart = new Chart("simplechart");
                policeResChart.addPlot("default", {type: Lines, enableCache:true});
                policeResChart.setTheme(theme);
                policeResChart.theme.plotarea.fill = "";
                policeResChart.fill = "";//the broder around the chart
                policeResChart.addSeries("data", policeResponses, {stroke:{color:"orange", width:3}});
                policeResChart.render();

                var myButton = dom.byId("btn");
                on (myButton, "click", function(evt){
                    request.post("test.jsp", {
                        data:{
                            color: "blue"
                        }
                        }).then(
                        function(response){
                            var newData = [
                                { y: 1 },
                                { y: 1 },
                                { y: 1 },
                                { y: 31 },
                                { y: 1 }];

                            policeResChart.updateSeries("data", newData);
                            policeResChart.render();

                        }//end response

                    );

                });//end onclick


        });//ends ready function

    });//ends require
```

whats also really strange is that only 1 render() can be called. so for example if I take the first (the on ready) render out and use the onclick render it will work. Im also noticing that ANYTHING i put after the second render in the onclick does not work. so alert("test") after the second render in the button push does nothing. Im not so sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, for some strange reason when I use                            `policeResChart.fullRender();` in the button push this works. Can someone explain why? I dont fully understand why the `render()` did not work.
Anyway, glad its "fixed".